# ZXING Barcode Decode error "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Tags: barcode, zxing, windows-store-apps

I am attempting to use the ZXING demo "WindowsRTDemo", and I can't get it to work.  The demo is downloaded [from this site](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/84413).

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
  protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        var cameras = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        if (cameras.Count < 1)
        {
           ScanResult.Text = "No camera found";
           return;
        }
        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[0].Id }; // 0 => front, 1 => back

        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        VideoCapture.Source = _mediaCapture;
        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();

        while (_result == null)
        {
           var photoStorageFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("scan.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
           await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoStorageFile);

           var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(3000, 2000);
           writeableBmp.SetSource(await photoStorageFile.OpenReadAsync());

           var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
           {
              TryHarder = true,
              AutoRotate = true
           };
           _result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);

           if (_result != null)
           {
              CaptureImage.Source = writeableBmp;
           }

           await photoStorageFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
        }

        await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        VideoCapture.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        CaptureImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ScanResult.Text = _result.Text;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        ScanResult.Text = ex.Message;
     }
  }
```

This code is modified from the downloaded demo in only two places.

1) I changed the VideoDeviceId from [1] to [0] because I only have a front facing camera.

2) The other change is in the creation of the new WriteableBitmap.  The downloaded demo has the size set to (640, 360).  When I tried it with that, I got an exception about index being outside the bounds of the array.  I figured this was because my webcam has a higher resolution than that, so I increased the size to match (and I've tried exceeding) the resolution of my webcam.  Now, when I run it, I get the following exception on the call to barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp):

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToManaged(IntPtr source, Object destination, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.CopyTo(IBuffer source, UInt32 sourceIndex, Byte[] destination, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 count)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(IBuffer source, UInt32 sourceIndex, Int32 count)
       at ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource..ctor(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap) in c:\Users\michael.jahn\Documents\SVN\ZXing.Net.Build\Source\lib\BitmapLuminanceSource.Silverlight.cs:line 50
       at ZXing.BarcodeReader.<.cctor>b__4(WriteableBitmap bitmap) in c:\Users\michael.jahn\Documents\SVN\ZXing.Net.Build\Source\lib\BarcodeReader.cs:line 60
       at ZXing.BarcodeReaderGeneric`1.Decode(T barcodeBitmap) in c:\Users\michael.jahn\Documents\SVN\ZXing.Net.Build\Source\lib\BarcodeReaderGeneric.cs:line 376
       at WindowsRT.MainPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Joseph Martinez\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsRTBarcodeDemo\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 53
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<.cctor>b__3(Object state)
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeInContext(Object thisObj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.Invoke()
  InnerException:
```

Again, this isn't my code, except for those two minor changes.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the WindowsRT demo. It should work now for you.
You can get the current version from the repository:
https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk
I used the solution from Damir and added some small other changes.

Comment: I downloaded the new demo, and it is still not working.  First of all, the first IF statement does not work because if there is only one camera, you still get an index out of bounds error because the array has only one entry.  So, I changed it to: if (cameras.Count == 1).

After I got past that, the program now hangs on the following line:

    await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoStorageFile);  

The program just hangs and the screen is just all black.

Comment: Also, did any files change besides MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs?  I only downloaded these two because the link you provided only lets me download one file at a time.  Is there a way that I can download the entire new project at once?  I tried downloading the whole thing again from the link I posted in my original question, but I got the old version again.

Comment: I changed the if-statement. Thanks for the hint.
You can get the whole source code with a subversion client and the url I mentioned above. I didn't change anything else than the two files and the project file. More important I didn't change the line which hangs. I can't test it because of missing Win8 pc with a camera. But I see no reason why it should hang now.

Comment: Ok, after some playing around, I got it to work.  It appears that the reason that it was hanging is that I was debugging the app, and setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop.  This dropped me into desktop mode, which stopped the camera, so it couldn't grab the image.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your hints which made the demo a little bit better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure (3000, 2000) is the exact resolution of your webcam? I suppose the above error could occur if the actual camera resolution was smaller than that.

Try determining the exact size of the image before creating `WriteableBitmap`:

```
await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), photoStorageFile);

var stream = await photoStorageFile.OpenReadAsync()
var bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(stream);
var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
stream.Seek(0);
writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the correct size of WriteableBitmap directly from the video device properties.
And you should await the Source setter.

```
var properties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
var videoEncodingProperties = properties as VideoEncodingProperties;
writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)videoEncodingProperties.Width, (int)videoEncodingProperties.Height);
await writeableBmp.SetSourceAsync(await photoStorageFile.OpenReadAsync());
```